# Nested loops counting upwards and downwards with stars

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to solve task with the usage of nested loops. My code below

```js
var n = 5;
var lineOfStars = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    if (j <= i) { // 1 <= 5 - 1 - 1 (3)
      lineOfStars += ' * ';
    } else {
      lineOfStars += ' ' + j + ' ';
    }
  }
  lineOfStars += '\n';
}
console.log(lineOfStars);
```

The result that im looking for is (i want to do it only with nested loops):

```
* 2 3 4 5
* * 3 4 5
* * * 4 5
* * * * 5
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * 5
* * * 4 5
* * 3 4 5
* 2 3 4 5
```

The code that ive shown does only half of the job. I need help. Thanks in advance

Comment: As you say, you've done half the job by counting upward. Just finish the job by counting downward.

Comment: Thanks for help. That's the comment i wasn't looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is closer to what you are wanting, still working on it.

```js
var n = 5;
var lineOfStars = '';
let i, j
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    if (j <= i) {
      lineOfStars += ' * ';
    } else {
      lineOfStars += ' ' + j + ' ';
    }
  }
  lineOfStars += '\n';
}
console.log(lineOfStars)
for (j = 5; j <= 5; j--) {
  if (j == 0) break;
  for (i = 5; i <= n; i--) {
    if (0 == 0) break;
    if (i <= j) {
      lineOfStars += ' ' + i + ' ';
    } else {
      lineOfStars += ' * ';
    }
  }
  lineOfStars += '\n';
}
let rev = lineOfStars.split('\n').reverse()
for (let z = 1; z <= rev.length - 1; z++) {
  if (rev[z].length != 0) {
    console.log(rev[z])
    lineOfStars += rev[z]
    lineOfStars += '\n';
  }
}
console.log(lineOfStars)
```

Comment: Thanks but the task is to do it with strings :/

Comment: Great job, had similar results. I dont know how to do it in one nested loop with if statements :/ hard

Comment: what did you come up with?

Comment: thats fine, keep it

Comment: great job bro :)